# Gnuplot vectors doesn't follow the plot data

Tags: gnuplot

I've been actually solving this for an hour on why this data plot :

```
  8.000000  -5.409915   8.000000   2.154234
 -8.000000  -5.409915   8.000000  -5.409915
 -8.000000   2.154234  -8.000000  -5.409915
  8.000000   2.154234  -8.000000   2.154234
  8.000000  -6.386620   8.000000   1.177529
 -8.000000  -6.386620   8.000000  -6.386620
 -8.000000   1.177529  -8.000000  -6.386620
 -8.000000  -6.386620  -8.000000   1.177529
```

renders this:

[image: plot]

This was plotted with `$ gnuplot -e "set term png; plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with vectors nohead" > tt.png"`

The first column of the data file tells where the tail of a vector at where x it lands and the second as where y it lands. The third and the fourth column, x and y respectively, tells where the head of a vector lands.

I've use the same x value of the tail of the vector and I think this is what caused it. If it's really the cause then it must be bug, but I doubt that it's not because in mathematics, a function takes an X and maps it to Y. A single X can't give two different result.

To give an idea on what I wanted with this data plot is to create a line segment from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2), and a vector seems like what I need for this.

gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8

Comment: it seems that there's a bug where both tail of vector, with the same x value, just adds together. so -8+-8 = -16 as what you see on the plot of a certain tail of a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with vectors` plot style takes four columns of data:

```
  x y delta-x delta-y
```

If your data file contains endpoint coordinates in columns 3 and 4 rather than deltas, you can deal with this using the command

```
  plot $data using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors
```

where as usual "$4" is short hand for "column(4)"

[image]

Comment: Strange that I get an invalid expression. "set term png; plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:(-):(-) with vectors". Was $3 $1 $2 $4 suppose to be a value?

Comment: Oh figure it out! I just used an scape sequence like backslash, so: `gnuplot -e "set term png; plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:(\$3-\$1):(\$4-\$2) with vectors" >
$desk/tt.png`